# Building QGIS. Is Qt6 supported?

Tags: qgis, windows, qt

I am in the process of building QGIS from source (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS) for Windows 10. I am using QtCreator 7.0.2 based on Qt 6.2.3 (MSVC 2019 , 64 bit).

Does the current source for QGIS support Qt6?

Answer (score 5):

Porting QGIS to Qt 6 is a work in progress as you can see in this [QGIS Enhancement Proposal](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/243).

A lot of developments, tests and workflows are made for building QGIS with Qt6 but at this current time, it's not available.

If you want to go further with this question, I advise you :

- [QGIS Developers list](https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/mailinglists.html#qgis-developers-list)
- [New Revolt chat](https://app.revolt.chat/invite/eRTmS1ZV)
- [QGIS GitHub repo](https://github.com/qgis/qgis)